# JAWS keyboard shortcuts firing click events on aria role="gridcell"

Tags: accessibility, roles, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I'm facing an issue where JAWS is firing click events when a JAWS-specific keyboard shortcut is used while a gridcell is focused and JAWS is in Form mode.

The sample below will end up producing the behavior I described:I find it easiest to reproduce this behavior in Firefox and with JAWS 17:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head><title>clicking issue</title></head>
<body>
      <table role="grid" summary="sample">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                   <td>
                         <a href="#" onclick="alert(event.type);">Gridcell Role Cell</a>
                   </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                   <td>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="testcheckbox">Gridcell Checkbox
                   </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>


      <input type="checkbox" name="testcheckbox2">Non-Gridcell Checkbox 2
</body>
</html>
```

If you tab navigate onto the "Click ME" cell and use a JAWS keyboard shortcut, e.g. insert+ctrl+b (display Buttons on page shortcut), a click event is fired on the focused element and the JS alert appears, reporting a "click" event.

Is this expected behavior of JAWS? How can I avoid triggering of elements when a keyboard shrotcut is used?

Comment: I'm sorry, why do you use the `presentation` role here? AFAIK, it shouldn't be used unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: I think that's a red herring. rule="grid" (and even no role on the table tag) produces identical behavior with regards to the clicking event problem.

Comment: Do you have a URL? I suspect you have a few issues stacking up here, such as `tabindex` on a `<td>` that has its role changed within a now de-semanticized `table` along with an `a` that has no `href`. Given what I am seeing just in this code, I think seeing the entire page is necessary.

Comment: Just performed a couple tests and I agree with @aardrian: we need a URL to pinpoint this. I couldn't reproduce this here, so probably JAWS behaves like this because of malformed HTML (no `tr`, no `href` on the link).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an externally available site to show it fully in-context. I did, however, update the sample HTML in the question to make it easier to reproduce in IE11 as well as Firefox. I'm able to get the results with the given HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your sample code. Removing `role="grid"` works fine with IE11 and JAWS17.

To get list of check box please press `insert+ctrl+x`.
if we have `role="grid"` then check box toggles while pressing `insert+ctrl+x`.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>clicking issue</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table summary="sample">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" onclick="alert(event.type);">Gridcell Role Cell</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="testcheckbox" id="gcCheckbox"><label for="gcCheckbox">Gridcell Checkbox</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <input type="checkbox" name="testcheckbox2" id="nonGcCheckbox"><label for="nonGcCheckbox">Non-Gridcell Checkbox 2</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Removing role="grid" isn't an option, the example served to exemplify the problem in its most basic form outside of my application. The aria roles are necessary.

Comment: Does the lack of role="grid" will skip the element when you navigate through the page? I have nested divs, forming a table (visually), which I'm trying to enhance for blind people to be able to interact as a grid or table by putting a role="grid" and on each cell role="gridcell". As far as know a plain div as a wrapper won't make a screen reader to enter in it's appropriate mode.